# How I can use pin request dialog in a Bluetooth connection?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, pairing

I have two devices with a custom app for Bluetooth connections.

But when I click on a device to pair,show this message:

[image]

And I want to ask for confirmation pin like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pNbd7RB.png]

I use this code:

```
//----------------------------I set the devices in a list--------------------------------------------------------------------

private void getPairedDevices() {

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();            
    if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
    {

        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
        {

            arrayListpaired.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress()+ "\n DescContents: " + device.describeContents()
                     + "\n BondState: " + device.getBondState()  
                     + "\n HashCode: " + device.hashCode()  
                     + "\n toString: " + device.toString()  
                     + "\n Class: " + device.getClass()   
                     + "\n Uuids: " + device.getUuids()
                     + "\n BTClass: " + device.getBluetoothClass()
                     + "\n   "
                     );
            arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


class ListItemClicked implements OnItemClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
        //bdClass = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
        Log.i("Log", "The dvice : "+bdDevice.toString());


       connect(bdDevice);
        Boolean isBonded = false;
        try {

            isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
            if(isBonded)
            {   
               getPairedDevices();
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
    }       
}
```

---

```
   private Boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bdDevice) { 
    Boolean bool = false;
    try {
        Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
        Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Class[] par = {};
        Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
        Object[] args = {};
        bool = (Boolean) method.invoke(bdDevice);//, args);// this invoke creates the detected devices paired.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bool.booleanValue();
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, try to reduce size of code to only relevant to your question parts.

Comment: Still with lot of commented out lines...